# How to implement a "scroll to load more" using Node.js and MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Node server using Express+Typescript that connects to a MongoDB database using Mongoose.
In my DB I have a collection called `Products` that the frontend (Angular 9) requests to display them.

Right now I just send a `GET` request and my server returns all the products:

```
public async getAll() {
        const products = await this.productModel.find({}).then(products => products).catch(() => false)

        if (!products)
            throw new Error('Could\'nt get products')

        return products
    }
```

in angular:

```
getAllProducts() {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>('http://127.0.0.1:3000/products/')
  }
```

My question is how can i retrieve the products by "chunks", like `n` products per request also without repeating products?

Answer (score 0):

you can use offset and limit send limit and offset in query and use it on MongoDB
e.g. for page 1 and 20 data per page offset 0 limit 20
     for page 2 and 20 data per page offset 20 limit 20  so on

```
  await this.productModel.find({}).skip(offset).limit(limit).then(products => products).catch(()
    => false)
```